# I'm trying to implement a sort table/table filter solution using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm currently trying to use the code found here: [Dropdown Table Filter](https://github.com/rbayliss/Dropdown-Table-Filter)

While I've got a demo table up and running, I've run into a snag. There's a rather large swath of information that I would like for the user to be able to search for Alphabetically. What I mean by this, is that i would like to use an A-Z dropdown, which would select multiple items, instead of having a HUGE menu that's listed in alphabetical order.

According to the documentation, I should be able to use the following code to do as such, but I am new to this and as such the instructions seems a bit vague.

```
    var options = {
  sortOpt: false,
  ...more settings here
}
$('#myTable').ddTableFilter(options);
```

If I could get some assistance with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

---

Oh my, sorry. I had changed it to:

```
    var options = {
```

sortOpt: true,
  ...more settings here
}

Which got the whole thing up and running in the first place, but I'm uncertain as to how I can modify it to my purposes. I am thinking I'll need to use "valueCallback", but am uncertain as to how to go about doing this.

Comment: Why do you think that `sortOpt: false` does what you want? From the docs: _"sortOpt: A boolean indicating whether or not to sort the options."_ ...I don't think that this jQuery plugin can do what you want without modification.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net) plug-in to be simply brilliant. Highly configurable, but does pretty much everything you could need straight of the box. Filtering (even of tables with several thousand rows) is incredibly fast, to the point where creating 'chapters' for the sort would not be necessary.